# Custom dialler for Internet Calls (Android)

Tags: android, sip, voip

I'm trying to get an idea of what's possible and what isn't in terms of using a custom dialler app for internet calls.

The idea is that the standard Android dialler be used when no internet connection is available, but use a custom-written VOIP dialler / caller app whenever an internet connection is available.
I see that in the Android call settings you can set it to use Internet calling whenever a connection is available. How does this work? Does this simply tell the native dialler app to use internet calling, or is there actually a specific Intent or something that gets fired when  an internet call is made so that I can open my custom SIP app?

And also, is the 'standard phone app' icon always linked to the standard phone app, or can you override this phone icon to open your custom VOIP app when a connection is present?

So basically, is there a way to seamlessly and automatically switch between the standard dialler and the custom SIP dialler based on whether or not the phone is connected to the internet?

If not, is this something that could be done by customizing Android?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four possible ways of doing what you want that I know of:

**1**. Replace the Android Dialer

This is hard and a lot of work.  The Android Dialer (last time I checked anyway) WAS the telephony stack in Android.  So to replace it you have to replace the complete telephony stack (including any public API) i.e. handle all cellular (and now sip) calls in and out of the device.  Also the only way to replace it is to root the device as it can't be replaced normally.

**2**. Provide your own Dialer that is separate to the main dialer.

This has it's advantages that you will never get into "trouble" with anything else.

**3**. Hook into the outbound call API ([ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL))

This is something that is pretty cool and I haven't seen any other OS allow you to do.  Basically you can trap when either the normal dialer starts to dial a number (or when another application starts to dial a number as well) and you can either allow it through, modify it or cancel it.  Behavior I've seen from sip clients is that they will cancel the call and put up a selection screen prompting where you want to send the call (sip, cellular or something else).

Here is an [example](http://androidlabs.org/short-experiments/broadcast-receivers/process-outgoing-calls/) of it's use.

The downsides are:

- You can be fighting with other applications to which gets first go.  There is a 'priority' setup, but all I've seen is everybody wants to be number one.
- On some Android devices where the OEM providers that own Dialer, they don't always fire it!!!

**4**. Detect when the dialer is shown and show your own dialer in front of it.

This works and does allow you to provide a nicer more integrated feel as you can provide call type selection within the dialer, as well as other custom number lookups but that can be a little tricky to do on some devices.

I would suggest **3** to begin with as it's pretty easy to do and you can get something up going pretty fast.  In code that I have worked on, we have done 2, 3 and 4 and also looked into 1.